# Como exibir imagens dinâmicas a partir de um ListView?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Criei uma *div* com um *ListView* onde é atribuído um *CheckBox* e uma *Imagem* que são carregados no *Page_Load*.

Preciso que, ao clicar em um dos *CheckBox* selecionando da imagem, a mesma seja criada dinamicamente em outra *Div* ao lado, sendo que no máximo o usuário possa selecionar 4 imagens da lista e após a escolha das imagens elas sejam gravadas o caminho da pasta para que outra vez que o usuário entra na mesma tela as imagens selecionadas anteriormente sejam carregadas.

Abaixo o que já tenho.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panelObjeto">
    <div style="position: relative; height: 300px; width: 200px; overflow-x: scroll;">
        <asp:ListView ID="livImagens" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanging="livImagens_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="itemplaceholder" runat="server">
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="border: solid 1px">
                    <td style="border: solid 1px">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxImagem" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Value") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>

    </div>
    <div id="divimagens" runat="server" style="position: absolute; left: 35%; top: 23%; height: 300px; width: 710px;">
        <p>Aqui será carregado as imagens</p> 
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Code behind.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Imagens/"));
        List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "~/Imagens/" + fileName));
        }
        livImagens.DataSource = files;
        livImagens.DataBind();
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Usar JavaScript é uma opção?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez sim, é uma opção, estou vendo se consigo também chamando um método através do evento OnCheckedChanged

Comment: Por que você não usa jQuery pra copiar o HTML das imagens selecionadas e jogar essas imagens como conteúdo da div que representa as imagens repetidas?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves não sei como fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da mesma forma que carrega a lista principal de imagens. Nesse bloco de código, você pode deixar assim:

```
<div id="divimagens" runat="server" style="position: absolute; left: 35%; top: 23%; height: 300px; width: 710px;">
       <asp:ListView ID="livImagensSelecionadas" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="itemplaceholder" runat="server">
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="border: solid 1px">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Value") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

e no behind:

```
List<ListItem> imgSelecionadas = new List<ListItem>();

protected void livImagens_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string imageUrl = ((sender as Control).FindControl("Image1") as Image).ImageUrl;
   imgSelecionadas.Add(new ListItem(imageUrl.replace("~/Imagens/",""), imageUrl));
   livImagensSelecionadas.DataSource = imgSelecionadas;
   livImagensSelecionadas.DataBind();
}
```

Algo mais ou menos nessa linha.

Comment: como eu poderia carregar as imagens depois de salva no banco ?

Comment: Depois de salvas no banco de dados, aí depende como você salvou a imagem. Se você salvou a imagem como um campo do tipo IMAGE ou VARBINARY, dá uma olhada com cuidado nesse link, vai te ajudar: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=175

Aqui tem a solução de como fazer o upload das imagens também, basta adaptar para você

Comment: É possível salvar a imagem como uma string base64 também.